# Google sheets: clasp push command fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, clasp

I am trying to push Google App Scripts code to cloud using the following command

```
clasp push
```

But it fails with the following error.

```
responseType: 'json',
retryConfig: {
  currentRetryAttempt: 3,
  retry: 3,
  httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
  noResponseRetries: 2,
  statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
}
},
 code: 500,
  errors: [
   {
    message: 'Unknown Error.',
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'backendError'
   }
]
```

It works when I push only a few files, so I don't whether it's related to storage limit or any other issue.

**Edit:**

I tried adding files directly to google app script project, then I encountered the following error on the last file:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
```

Please let me know if there is an issue with storage.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I would submit an issue/bug-report to Clasp's GitHub page at https://github.com/google/clasp. Seems like a bug or issue on Google's side.

Comment: You should check whether everything is correct with the source files you try to push (for example, trying to push `static` class fields [experimental] by accident caused it to respond with `404` one time). Please, update the question with answers to two questions: 1. Does the issue affect a certain amount of files? And, since you said that some pushes work - try removing files one-by-one: 2. Which of the files causes `push` to fail?

Comment: @OlegValter, I did your #2 suggestion but it seems there is the restriction to the storage limit. Because the file which caused the issue can be pushed individually.

Comment: Have you tried ```clasp push --force```?

Comment: Hi @Jayakrishnan, thanks for clarifying - never heard of any cap on script storage, indeed this is worth opening an issue with clasp maintainers (pushing ~800Mb file + 42 dumies works fine for me). Not sure if `--force` option will make a difference, in context of clasp it just overwrites remote manifest

Comment: @OlegValter, the issue was due to some javascript code that google doesn't understand. Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500823/tool-to-compile-google-app-script-locally

Comment: I don't think there are tools that can help you, but there are a few checks you can do: are you on v8 runtime? If so, do you use any of te experimental features, like static class properties? Modules?

Comment: Hi! Was the origin of the issue then a JS piece of code Google is not understanding? In that case, what is the line of code that is causing the problem?  Bare in mind that Apps Script does not support some recent JS functionalities as its ```v8``` version works with ```ES6``` but it does not support some modules, [check this article to learn more about this](https://www.labnol.org/es6-google-apps-script-v8-200206).