# Tool to compile Google App Script locally

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, clasp

I am developing a sheet add on using JavaScript framework and using clasp to push the files to google drive.

The problem is that clasp push command fails for some JavaScript code by simply saying:

```
code: 500, errors: [ { message: 'unknown error.', domain: 'global', reason: 'backenderror' } ]
```

I think the App script doesn't allow certain JavaScript code.

So I am looking for a tool that can compile the JavaScript code and Google App script code and point me the exact location of exception or at least the reason for the exception.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the [Apps Script Starter](https://git.io/JvW61) and it will transpile the code with Babel before pushing with clasp.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal, I have the javascript output files of angular, will still your App Script starter? Because I tried and it gives me many errors.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to run? Take into account that Apps Script uses [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015) of Javascript.

Comment: @Jescanellas, it's the javascript output files of the angular application.